# Event to use for binding Angular directive on image load

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to integrate [this jQuery plugin](http://jqueryflipbook.jshedden.com/) into an Ionic app. I'm comfortable with the idea of creating an Angular directive to wrap the plugin, but I'm struggling to get it working.

Here's the directive:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])

.directive('flipbook', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) { 
    return { 
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { 
          elem.bind('load', function () { 
            $(elem).flipbook({
              speed: 125,
              autoplay: false,
              play: 'button#playbutton',
              stop: 'button#pausebutton',
              rewind: 'button#rewindbutton'
            });
          });
        } 
    };
}]);
```

And here's the relevant template:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{ album.title }}">
<ion-content>

<div flipbook>
    <div class="gallery-item" ng-repeat="photo in album.photos | orderBy: 'created_at'">
        <img ng-if="photo.thumbnail" ng-src="{{ photo.thumbnail }}"></img>
    </div>                     
    </div>                     
</div>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The photos are fetched using an AJAX request, and then pulled in using `ng-repeat`.

Using the Chrome debugger I've been able to establish that the `link` function gets called, but the function that binds to the `load` event never gets called. So presumably I'm not binding to the correct event.

Given that I want the images to finish loading before I initialise the jQuery plugin, what event should I be binding to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no builtin event that fires when a `ng-repeat` has completed. You can however create a simple directive that does this trick:

```
app.directive('postRepeat', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
      $('#book').flipbook();
    }
  };
});
```

Apply it on the `img` elements inside the `ng-repeat` and you're good to go.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XwpkFS3wIMnteHXbm7g1?p=preview) as proof.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind **load** event to **IMG** tag instead of the **DIV**. Replace `elem` with `elem.find("img")`:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', []).directive('flipbook', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) { 
        return { 
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { 
              elem.find("img").bind('load', function () { 
                $(elem).flipbook({
                  speed: 125,
                  autoplay: false,
                  play: 'button#playbutton',
                  stop: 'button#pausebutton',
                  rewind: 'button#rewindbutton'
                });
              });
            } 
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: No, doesn't resolve the issue. At the point when it's triggered, the images have not yet been inserted using `ng-repeat`, so `elem.find("img")` returns nothing. The field `album` is populated using an AJAX request, and that contains the photo URLs, so the images only come in once that's finished.

Comment: Correction, the image tags have not yet been inserted - obviously, the images themselves will only be inserted after the tags have been created.